# Error : java.lang.VerifyError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager

Tags: android

i am trying to evaluate string expression is
12 >=(2063+2065) && 12>(2062-2064) for that i used below code and i have also add jsr223.jar

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String foo = "12 >=(2063+2065) && 12>(2062-2064)";
Log.e("test","eval "+engine.eval(foo));
```

but getting flowing error

`java.lang.VerifyError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager`

Comment: `ScriptEngineManager` may rely on things that are not in the Android SDK. I would recommend that you not use `ScriptEngineManager`, but instead work with a language interpreter directly. For expressions like you describe, there are various Java expression evaluation libraries that might work.

Comment: @CommonsWare  you are right i used https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx  and its working.